# WP7 - post json data to Web Service

Tags: json, windows-phone-7

I want to know the best way to send a small json string/ data to a web service. I can use WebClient or httpwebrequest that's not the issue, but i am mainly concerned about how to convert the string into json format and post with the request.

As suggested , here i am using json.net , following is the code :

```
 Uri url = new Uri("http://example.com");




         //Create the web request object
        HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        webRequest.Method = "POST";
        webRequest.ContentType = "application/json";

        // Start the request
        webRequest.BeginGetRequestStream(new AsyncCallback(GetRequestStreamCallback), webRequest);


void GetRequestStreamCallback(IAsyncResult asynchronousResult)
    {
        HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)asynchronousResult.AsyncState;
        // End the stream request operation
        Stream postStream = webRequest.EndGetRequestStream(asynchronousResult);



        //
        JObject json =
            new JObject(
            new JProperty("customer", new JObject
            (
            new JProperty("phoneNumber", "07700555555"),
            new JProperty("name", "John")
            ))
            ,

            new JProperty("pickupAddress", new JObject
            (
            new JProperty("street", "1 Seagull Lane"),
            new JProperty("city", "London"),
            new JProperty("county", "London"),
            new JProperty("postcode", "E000XX"),
            new JProperty("country", "England"),
            new JProperty("longitude", "10.18"),
            new JProperty("latitude", "12.214")
            ))
            ,
            new JProperty("destinationAddress", new JObject
            (
            new JProperty("county", "London"),
            new JProperty("street", "1 Snow Lane"),
            new JProperty("longitude", "1.79"),
            new JProperty("latitude", "1.294"),
            new JProperty("postcode", "E00XX"),
            new JProperty("country", "England"),
            new JProperty("city", "London")
            ))
            ,


           new JProperty("pickupTime", "1311467121460"),
           new JProperty("notes", "some notes"),
           new JProperty("accountNumber", "account1"),
          new JProperty("accountPassword", "account password")


        );

        //



        // Create the post data
        // Demo POST data 

        //byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json.ToString());
        //byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("1233456");


        //
        JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
        serializer.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore;

        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(postStream))
        using (JsonWriter writer = new JsonTextWriter(sw))
        {
            //serializer.Serialize(writer, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(json));
             json.WriteTo(writer,null);

        }

        //



        // Add the post data to the web request
        //postStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
        postStream.Close();

        // Start the web request
        webRequest.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(GetResponseCallback), webRequest);
    }

    void GetResponseCallback(IAsyncResult asynchronousResult)
    {
        try
        {
            HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)asynchronousResult.AsyncState;
            HttpWebResponse response;

            // End the get response operation
            response = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.EndGetResponse(asynchronousResult);
            Stream streamResponse = response.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(streamResponse);
            var Response = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
            MessageBox.Show(Response);
            streamResponse.Close();
            streamReader.Close();
            response.Close();

        }
        catch (WebException e)
        {
            // Error treatment
            // ...
        }
    }
```

Now the code seems to be ok , json data is created ok , but response from server is showing : "the server response  e = {"The remote server returned an error: NotFound."}"

I don't know what's going wrong , please help friends ! Some one told me that i have to add something in header of the request i.e. The header should show: booking = {...JSON...}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the built in [DataContractJsonSerializer Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer%28v=VS.95%29.aspx).

Alternatively, you may get better performance with [json.net](http://json.codeplex.com/).

Comment: This class is present in Silverlight, it is not present on Windows Phone 7

Comment: @Gurpreet  This calls is present but it's  in a different assembly which is not included by default. Simply add a reference to System.ServiceModel.Web

Comment: Thanks Matt, for your help. I am using json.net as per your recommendation but i am getting the server response as : e = {"The remote server returned an error: NotFound."}. I have checked that the json data is created well and serialized.